Dirac Points: Triangular vs. Honeycomb Lattices
I'm reading the paper 'Honeycomb Lattice Potentials and Dirac Points' by Fefferman&Weinstein. To my understanding they claim that the existence of Dirac Cones at K/K' points is entirely determined by the honeycomb symmetry of the potential (Definition 2.1). They point out that 'triangular lattice potentials' also satisfy this definition (Example 1).
Does that mean that the band structure of triangular lattices also features Dirac Cones at K/K' points? This seems to contradict the results of a simple TB calculation and somewhat undermines the special focus on 'honeycomb'-potentials since triangular lattices are more mathematically straightforward. What am I misunderstanding?
